# RegexpError in Ruby when parsing \p{IsBasicLatin} character property

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, jruby, soap4r

I'm using JRuby 1.7.18 and have even tried this in JRuby 9000 (latest version) where I get the same error. I'm using the `soap-4r` and `nokogiri` libraries to parse a wsdl xml file.

When the below part of the wsdl is parsed

```
<xs:pattern value="[\p{IsBasicLatin}]*"/>
```

I get the following error

```
RegexpError: (RegexpError) invalid character property name <IsBasicLatin>: /\A[\p{IsBasicLatin}]*\z/n
nokogiri/XmlSaxParserContext.java:252:in `parse_with'
nokogiri/XmlSaxParserContext.java:252:in `parse_with'
nokogiri/XmlSaxParserContext.java:252:in `parse_with'
```

In Ruby 1.9, which is one of the Ruby versions that JRuby 1.7.18 is compatible with, I read that character blocks like `\p{IsBasicLatin}` are not supported. But scripts like `\p{Latin}` are supported. I've tried changing `IsBasicLatin` to `Latin` and even tried a few other ones like `InBasicLatin` and `InBasic_Latin` but they all return the same error.

This is both in JRuby 1.7.18 and JRuby 9000 which is the latest version.

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's `In_Basic_Latin`. Maybe the regexp's encoding isn't Unicode (`u` modifier for UTF-8 but that should be the default) or JRuby 9000 doesn't support character properties (at least those) yet?

Comment: @cremno I tried `In_Basic_Latin` and got the same error. Also, I thought it was the Unicode problem too, so I've searched through the nokogiri source code and it's encoding is definitely getting set to `UTF-8`. It's hardcoded in there. Unless its somehow getting lost when it goes over to Java. If you notice in my error log above the source files are actually java classes.

Comment: Report it to the JRuby team. `IsBasicLatin` is wrong (in Ruby) but `In_Basic_Latin` should work. Editing the file to fix the error is okay, isn't it?

Comment: @cremno yes that's what I mean when I said I tried `In_Basic_Latin`. I edited the wsdl file so it used that instead of `IsBasicLatin`. I guess I'll have to get in touch with the JRuby developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the name of the character property is actually `In_Basic_Latin` and not `IsBasicLatin`. Modern versions of Ruby (MRI or CRuby to be specific) use the regular expression library Onigmo. The official Ruby docs don't list all Unicode properties but luckily [Onigmo does](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/doc/UnicodeProps.txt).

Apparently JRuby doesn't seem to implement (at least) the Unicode block ones. However information (name and range) about blocks are [publicly accessible](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt). `\p{In_Basic_Latin}` is therefore equivalent to `[\u0000-\u007F]`. So is `[[:ascii:]]`.

Comment: Changing it from [\p{In_Basic_Latin}] to [\u0000-\u007F] worked, thank you!